# Parse HTML by line

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I am parsing an HTML webpage with Python and Beautiful Soup (I am open to other solutions, though). I am wondering if it is possible to parse the file based on a line of HTML, i.e., `get the td tag from line3`. Is this possible?

Comment: whats line3? can you post your code please

Comment: I am wondering why you want to parse by line numbers. If you are looking for the 3rd `td` tag, parsers can already get you that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider this example: `http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/python-on-the-web/web-scraping-with-beautifulsoup/` there is line-by-line processing and matching of href(you need td)

additionaly consider: `soup.find_all("td", limit=3)`