# HTML parsing line by line

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a python code intended to parse HTML. The objective here is to find strings in each line, and change them as seen below:

Original: "Criar Alerta"

```
<li><a href="http://..." target="_blank">Criar Alerta</a></li>
```

Expected Result: "Create Alert"

```
<li><a href="http://..." target="_blank">Create alert</a></li>
```

Then, to assure that I'm creating a new HTML with the same structure of the original, I need to parse the later line by line, identify the string, and change it for its equivalent from a dictionary.

I saw [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=soup#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) that BeautifulSoup can parse specific tags. I tried it, but I'm not sure about the result.

Then I ask: Is it possible to proceed line-by-line parsing with BeautifulSoup, given that it works with tags, and there are multiple tags for each line?

Thanks in advance,

Tiago

Comment: I saw a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19393524/parse-html-by-line) that lead me to the [link](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/index.html?highlight=soup#parsing-only-part-of-a-document) in my question.

Comment: I think you need to be a little more specific. Can you give an example of a few lines, the relevant dictionary and the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the following is what you are looking for.

Let's use 3 lines, two of which contain words in your dictionary, and one doesn't - just to test the code:

```
rep = """
      <li class="current"><a  style="color:#00233C;" href="index.html"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Início</a></li>
      <li class="current"><a  style="color:#00233C;" href="index.html"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Nunca</a></li>
      <li class="current"><a  style="color:#00233C;" href="index.html"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Criar Alerta</a></li>
    """
```

And use your dictionary (hint: it's never a good idea to define a dictionary as `dict`; it's just asking for trouble somewhere down the road...)

```
rep_dict = {
"Início": "Start",
"Ajuda": "Help",
"Criar Alerta": "Create Alert",
"Materiais e Estruturas": "Structures and Materials" 
}
```

Now to the code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(rep, 'lxml')

only_a_tags = soup.find_all('a')

for item in range(len(only_a_tags)):
    for word in rep_dict:
        if word in str(only_a_tags[item]):
            print(str(only_a_tags[item]).replace(word,rep_dict[word]))
```

Output:

```
<a href="index.html" style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Start</a>
<a href="index.html" style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Create    Alert</a>
```

The item containing "nunca" was not printed because "nunca" is not in `rep_dict`.

Comment: The code worked pretty fine with my html file. I'll write the dictionary in a specific .py file, since it has 200+ entries, and still can be updated. You're correct about the 'dict' name.
Thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0):

@Jack Fleeting

In the example below, I want to replace "Início" by "Start":

Original:

```
<li class="current"><a  style="color:#00233C;" href="index.html"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Início</a></li>
```

Expected result:

```
<li class="current"><a  style="color:#00233C;" href="index.html"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Start</a></li>
```

An example from the dictionary:

```
dict = {
    "Início": "Start",
    "Ajuda": "Help",
    "Criar Alerta": "Create Alert",
    "Materiais e Estruturas": "Structures and Materials"
    ...
}
```

Below is the code I've written, to practice HTML parsing with BeautifulSoup.
(I noticed that all strings to be replaced are inside "a" tags, then I used SoupStrainer("a"))

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer

with open(html_file, 'rb') as src:
    doc = src.read()
    src.close()

only_a_tags = SoupStrainer("a")
parse_1 = 'html.parser'
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, parse_1, parse_only=only_a_tags)

print(soup.prettify())
```

The original line is parsed and printed as follows:

```
<a href="index.html" style="color:#00233C;">
 <i class="icon icon-home">
 </i>
 Início
</a>
```

Given the print above, I'm not certain, if I'll be able to obtain the expected result.

My intention is to find the string(s) for each line, then search in the dictionary for its equivalent, and perform the replacement.

By now, I want to know how to perform this replacement of strings, using BeatifulSoup. 
After it, I will write a 'for' loop, to finally perform the replacement for all of the lines in the HTML file.

My first attempt (berfore knowing about BeautifulSoup) was to work on a .txt version of the HTML file read as binary, wich proved itself very time-consuming and unproductive.