# HTML Editing in Python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm working on a code to translate strings in HTML.

More specifically, my objective is to perform string replacement. The steps are: file parsing, identifying the string in line (if there is one), and finally replacing this string by its translated version, taken from a dictionary.

I got valuable help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56738735/html-parsing-line-by-line), on html parsing and string replacement for each line.

To open the html file as a txt, and sweep through it line by line, I took an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355225/edit-and-create-html-file-using-python).

Using knowledge from both the examples, I wrote the code below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import SoupStrainer
from html_dictionary import port_eng

def str_replace_port_eng(file_name, tag_name):

with open(file_name, 'rb') as src:
    doc = src.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(doc, 'html.parser')
    src.close()

only_tag_name = soup.find_all(str(tag_name))

with open("new_file.html", "w") as outf:
    for line in soup:
        for html_line in range(len(only_tag_name)):
            pt_word = str(only_tag_name[html_line].text).strip()
            pt_word = pt_word.strip('+')
            pt_word = pt_word.strip(' ')

            if pt_word != "":
                en_word = port_eng[pt_word]
                new_line = (str(only_tag_name[html_line]).replace(pt_word, en_word))
                outf.writelines(new_line)
            else:
                en_word = pt_word
                new_line = (str(only_tag_name[html_line]).replace(pt_word, en_word))
                outf.writelines(new_line)

newpg = str_replace_port_eng("input_test.html", "a")
```

Input file (example):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <!--<![endif]-->

<body>

 <div style="padding-top:0px;height:100%;" id="wrap">
 
  <div style="padding-bottom:0px;" id="header" class="ie-dropdown-fix">
  
  <!-- /// HEADER  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

   <div style="margin-left:10px;" class="row">
    <div class="span3">
    
     <!-- // Logo // 
     <a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="_layout/images/logo.png" alt="" class="responsive-img" /></a>
     -->
     
    </div><!-- end .span3 -->
    <div  style="color:#00233C;width:1100px;background-color:#FFFFFF;margin-right:0px" class="span6">
    
     <!-- // Dropdown Menu // -->
     <ul style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;width:1100px;" id="dropdown-menu" class="fixed">
      <li class="current"><a  style="color:#00233C;" href="..."><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Início</a></li>
      <li><a  style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;" href="#"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Ajuda <small class="mute">+</small></a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Classificação da Informação</a></li> 
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Reúso de Ativos Digitais</a></li>            
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Biblioteca</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>       
        <li><a href="#">Alerta <small class="mute">+</small></a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Criar Alerta</a></li> 
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Criar Alerta Múltiplo</a></li>            
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Aviso ou Notícia</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Busca <small class="mute">+</small></a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Busca Simples</a></li>
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Busca Avançada</a></li>         
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Documentos <small class="mute">+</small></a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Carregar Novo Documento</a></li>
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Editar Documento</a></li>             
         </ul>
        </li>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Expected Output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]>    <html class="ie7" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]>    <html class="ie8" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]>    <html class="ie9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gt IE 9)|!(IE)]><!--> <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <body>

 <div style="padding-top:0px;height:100%;" id="wrap">
 
  <div style="padding-bottom:0px;" id="header" class="ie-dropdown-fix">
  
  <!-- /// HEADER  //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->

   <div style="margin-left:10px;" class="row">
    <div class="span3">
    
     <!-- // Logo // 
     <a href="index.html" id="logo"><img src="_layout/images/logo.png" alt="" class="responsive-img" /></a>
     -->
     
    </div><!-- end .span3 -->
    <div  style="color:#00233C;width:1100px;background-color:#FFFFFF;margin-right:0px" class="span6">
    
     <!-- // Dropdown Menu // -->
     <ul style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;width:1100px;" id="dropdown-menu" class="fixed">
      <li class="current"><a  style="color:#00233C;" href="..."><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Start</a></li>
      <li><a  style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;" href="#"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a>
       <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a></li> 
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Digital Asset Reuse</a></li>            
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a></li>
         </ul>
        </li>       
        <li><a href="#">Alerta <small class="mute">+</small></a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a></li> 
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a></li>            
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Busca <small class="mute">+</small></a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a></li>
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a></li>         
         </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a>
         <ul>
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a></li>
          <li><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a></li>             
         </ul>
        </li>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actual Output:

```html
<a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a><a href="..." style="color:#00233C;"><i class="icon icon-home"></i>  Home</a><a href="#" style="color:#00233C;margin-left:10px;"><i class="icon icon-question-sign"></i>  Help <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="#">FAQ <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Information Security</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Reuse of Digital Assets</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Library</a><a href="#">Alert <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Create Multiple Alert</a><a href="..." target="_blank">News</a><a href="#">Search <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Simple Search</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Advanced Search</a><a href="#">Documents <small class="mute">+</small></a><a href="..." target="_blank">Load New Document</a><a href="..." target="_blank">Edit Document</a>
```

And now I'm looking for the error in the code, and how I can fix it.

Thanks in advance,

Tiago

Comment: The loop that is followed under `with open(file_name, 'rb') as src:`, iterates over all your files of interest. However, after that loop ends, you are ending up with only the `soup` of your last file. Was this intentional ? Because, if it's not, then you might want to bring the rest of your code under that loop.

Comment: @Argon Thanks for your comment. I didn't noticed that the loop as seen in the post will return only the `soup`obj. I saw this error after removing the 1st `for` from the code; the result was the translated strings as a single line.

Comment: To be able to search for the strings, I get a `soup` obj from the html and iterate over it. In the end I need the whole html, just with the strings replaced. The output file, as given by the code, begins with the 1st line with a replaced string, letting behind  those lines prior to it.
Is there any way to iterate over all the html and replace the strings? I mean, not iterate over `soup` but edit it, using the (let's say) line of the html as a reference?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found was to copy the content from the `.html` file, paste it in a `.py` file, and start the editing work from there.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from html_dictionary import port_eng    # Dictionary
from html_input_file import raw_text    # Input file: .py file with string
                                        # defined by triple quotes (""" """)

rtx = list(raw_text.split('\n'))
ans_list = []                           # List of lines with replaced string
off_list = []                           # List of items not found in dictionary, and index of occurrence

for raw_line in rtx:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(raw_line, "lxml")
    tag_cont = soup.text                # tag content
    tag_cont = tag_cont.strip('+')
    tag_cont = tag_cont.strip(' ')

    if tag_cont in port_eng.keys():
        en_word = port_eng[tag_cont]
        new_item = str(raw_line).replace(tag_cont, en_word)

    else:l
        en_word = tag_cont
        new_item = str(raw_line).replace(tag_cont, en_word)
        if tag_cont not in off_list:    
            off_list.append(tuple([tag_cont, rtx.index(raw_line)]))

    ans_list.append(new_item)

return ans_list, off_list
```

I take the output directly form the screen via `print()` and copy it into a new `.html` file - it's not the most elegant solution indeed, but works.